# Not showing folder structure after installing pod in development pods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec, podfile

I have files structure like as below in my local framework.

[image]

My podspec configuration is -

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'ARToolKit'
  s.version          = '1.0.0'
  s.license          = {
    :type => 'Apps',
    :text => 'Copyright'
  }
  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/abc/ARToolKit'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'XYZ' => 'abc@gmail.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/abc/ARToolKit.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.summary          = 'ARToolKit component within Apps'
    s.description      = <<-DESC
TODO: Add long description of the pod here.
                       DESC
  
  s.subspec 'UIKit' do |subspec|
    subspec.source_files = 'ARToolKit/Source/UIKit/**/*.{swift}'
    subspec.resource_bundles = {
      'ARToolKit' => ['ARToolKit/Source/UIKit/**/*.{xcassets}']
    }
  end
  
  s.subspec 'Utility' do |subspec|
    subspec.source_files = 'ARToolKit/Source/Utility/**/*.{swift,storyboard}'
  end
end
```

And podfile configuration is -

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'ProjectName' do
  
  # Pods for ProjectName
  
  pod 'ARToolKit', path: '../'
  
  target 'NahjulBalaghahProTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end
```

When I am running `pod install` in terminal then after installing pod, folder structure is not showing as in framework, showing as below -

[image]

How can I achieve folder structure in development pods? I want same folder structure as in framework.